# call methods of subclass in main

Tags: java, object

i have a class called "Student" as parent and 2 Subclasses (Undergraduate and Postgraduate) ...

```
    Student[] student;
    student=new Student[10];
```

and i need to set values in an array inside a subclass ..

so my question is how to call that method from main ??

this is the method i want to call

```
public void setInternship(boolean Internship){
    this.Internship=Internship;}
```

and its inside undergraduate class

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you have a common base class and you want to provide different specific functionalities which belongs to all subclasses, you should use interfaces or abstract methods, eg:

```
abstract class Student {
  abstract void setInternship(boolean internship);
}

class Undergraduate {
  void setInternship(boolean internship) { this.internship = internship; }
}
```

This is not always the case, since you may have a situation in which only some subclasses are able to respond to a specific functionality, in that situation you have two choices:

- call the method on the instance before the implicit upcast to its base class
- use an explicit downcast, which breaks type safety and should be avoided when it is not really necessary

The first case is simple:

```
Undergraduate ud = new Undergraduate();
ud.setInternship(true);
students[0] = ud;
```

The second case is simple too:

```
students[0] = new Undergraduate();
((Undegraduate)students[0]).setInternship(true);
```

Casting a type to another, unallowed, type, will raise a `ClassCastException` at runtime. To avoid that, you can use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (students[0] instanceof Undergraduate)
  ((Undegraduate)students[0]).setInternship(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that a particular `Student` in your array is actually an `Undergraduate`, then you can cast it:

```
student[0] = new Undergraduate(...);
Undergraduate undergraduate = (Undergraduate)student[0];  // This is the cast
undergraduate.setInternship(internship);
```

Comment: there are 10 student that the user will enter details about including if they're undergrads or postgraduate, and I'll need to print those details if the user wants, so how do i print all the student [0] details ..

Comment: @user3834329 Add a virtual `print()` method to `Student` and implement it in `Undergraduate` and `Graduate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of both undergraduates and postgraduates, you can loop through the array, check if the index location of that array contains an instance of an undergraduate class and then call the method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to call the method of a subclass, the actual object must be of that subclass. For example, you will have:

```
Student[] students = new Students[1];
students[0] = new Undergraduate();
((Undergraduate))students[0]).setInternship(new Internship());
```

Or if you have a bigger array without knowing the actual type of the object, you must check before the type in order to avoid a `ClassCastException`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.length; ++i) {
    if (students[i] instanceof Undergraduate) {
        ((Undergraduate)students[i]).setInternship(new Internship());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The field you are trying to initialize 'Internship' is not visible to base class 'Student'. For initializing the child class ('undergraduate') field you need to type cast the object of type 'student' in to 'undergraduate'

```
Student[] student;
student=new Student[10];
((UnderGraduate)student).setInternship(true);
```

I don't know your use case but ideally your design should be such that Parent Class should know nothing about the fields of child class, so in your case Student class should not know about fields present in 'Undergraduate and Postgraduate'

Ideally all the attributes of a student e.g. name, age, DOB etc should go with Student Class and you should add specific attributes of Undergraduate and Postgraduate to the respective classes.

Hope this helps.